# Linear map from a tensor product of vector spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra, linear-transformations, tensor-products

I have to solve the following: Let $V$ be a complex vector space with dimension $n$ and $L(V)$ the space of linear transformations from $V$ to $V$. Also define
$$c:L(V)\otimes L(V)\to L(V)$$
such that the image on a pure tensor $T\otimes S$ is $c(T\otimes S)=T\circ S$.

**(i)** Prove that $c$ is linear.

**(ii)** Compute the nullity of $c$.

To prove the first part I think there are two possible ways: only around definitions and linearity of the tensor product or using tensor product universal property to the bilinear map $g:L(V)\times L(V)\to L(V)$ such that $g(S,T)=S\circ T$.

Now, for the second one I am not sure what tools of linear or commutative algebra I can use. Could someone give me an idea? Thanks!

Comment: the image of this linear transformation should be easy to calculate, and thus the rank of this linear map is obvious. How does one relate rank to nullity?

Comment: Oh I see. It is clear that $c$ is surjective. So the nullity of $c$ is the difference between the dimension of $L(V)\otimes L(V)$ and the dimension of $L(V)$, i.e., $n^4-n^2$. Is it right?

Comment: yup that's exactly right